# How can I fix g++ Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 error?

Tags: c++, string, macos, gcc

First of all, I've read the related content on Stackoverflow on this problem but I still can't solve it. I've simplified my code as much as possible.

I've only a custom class with .h and .cpp files but I get error while trying to create an instance of this class from main.cpp.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Customer.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Customer a("string");

    return 0;
}
```

**Customer.h**

```
using namespace std;

class Customer {
public:
    Customer(string input);
};
```

**Customer.cpp**

```
#include "Customer.h"
using namespace std;

Customer::Customer(string input) {
}
```

The error message I get is the following?

```
  gcc *.cpp -o k


  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
        _main in main-40340f.o
    "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
        _main in main-40340f.o
    "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
        _main in main-40340f.o
    "std::terminate()", referenced from:
        ___clang_call_terminate in main-40340f.o
    "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
        ___clang_call_terminate in main-40340f.o
    "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
        _main in main-40340f.o
        Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in main-40340f.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I run Mac OS X 10.9 and Sublime Text 3. gcc -v gives the following:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

It compiles without problem when I write empty constructors instead of these.

What could cause this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You should `#include <string>`.
2. To compile C++ code on OS X, use `clang++` or `g++`.

Answer (score 5):

Use `g++` instead of `gcc`:

```
$ g++ *.cpp -o k
```

and then the compiler driver knows to link-in the C++ runtime library.  Given it's actually `clang` you are using, and not `gcc`, then this is better:

```
$ clang++ *.cpp -o k
```

Comment: While it doesn't matter in this case, `g++` and `clang++` are different under OS X. `g++` will use `libstdc++` while `clang++` will use `libc++`. Both do use the LLVM frontend though.

Comment: @sharth Well that's interesting, and will have an effect if 3rd-party libraries are being used.

Answer (score 3):

Use "g++ "instead of "gcc" to compile and link your application. It automatically knows about the C++ libraries that need to be included.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Command Line Tools.
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

Answer (score -1):

g++ main.cpp(or Customer.cpp) -o k    is not enough. You should compile them at the same time. 
"g++ main.cpp Customer.cpp (and other *.cpp(s) if you have)  -o target "
 will work well.